# Could not save the uploaded image to the image view using file chooser

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

i wanted to upload an `Image`(profile picture) to an `ImageView` which is set `empty` initially. I used `FileChooser` to upload the `Image` on a `Button` action. but when i close the `Scene` and reopen it the `ImageView` dont have the `Image`. I think this is because this action don't specify an `Image`on the `ImageView`in the fxml `File`. I just wanted to how to do it. Thanks.

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(uPUploadButton.getScene().getWindow());
if (file != null){
   Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
   userpanelImageView.setImage(image);
}
```

Comment: You must provide code detailing your attempt so far, else it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: @HamishD i have edited my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: when you say "when i close the scene and reopen it" do you mean close the program entirely and run again or do you mean switching scenes to a different scene and switching back?

Comment: @HamishD Yes, when this scene is opened my previous scene will be closed. So it's like closing entire platform. And i start from beginning.

Comment: If you are closing the program entirely then your image will be lost unless you store the file somewhere locally and reload it on application start. Alternately if you are switching between 2 scenes try using a single instance of each rather than creating a new instance between switching of scenes, this will persist the data of any elements you have until the application closes

Comment: @HamishD yes that's what i want to know, how to store that image which is choosen and load it onto that image view everytime the scene starts after that.

Comment: I will not be able to explain in a single answer or comment so i'd reccomend you check out [this article](https://code.makery.ch/blog/persisting-data-in-java/) for an idea on how you can persist the data through shutdown

Comment: @HamishD ok, anyway thanks for your time.